# How do I render an Array of Strings in React without using wrapper?

Tags: reactjs

I want to to render an Array of strings like this `a = ["a", "b", "c"]` without a wrapper such as `<div>a</div>` but also follow the key={index} rule of React

I thought about using Fragments <> but I found out that we couldn't place the key prop into it.

Currently, my code is this

```
<Paragraph>{a.map((item) => ({item}))}<Paragraph>
```

So, I couldn't follow the key={index} rule of React here. I wanted to do like this because I think it's easier to select texts using `window.getSelection()` to get texts only and push them into an Array of Strings.

I expect to render something like this

```
<Paragraph>
 <key="0">"a"</>
 <key="1">"b"</>
 <key="2">"c"</>
</Paragraph>
```

not like this

```
<Paragraph>
 <span key="0">"a"</span>
 <span key="1">"b"</span>
 <span key="2">"c"</span>
</Paragraph>
```

Hopefully, I made it clear about my question. Thank you for reading! I am looking forward to see your responses!

Comment: You want the key, but key has to be property of something, but that something got to be a wrapper. What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a component, which will render your letter, which you can then place a `key` on. So something like this:

```
const Character = ({ letter }) => <>{letter}</>;

const App = ({ arrayOfLetters }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arrayOfLetters.map((letter, index) => (
        <Character key={index} letter={letter} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const arrayOfLetters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App arrayOfLetters={arrayOfLetters} />, rootElement);
```

This will then produce the HTML you wanted: `<div class="App">abcd</div>` without additional HTML elements render, allowing `window.getSelection()` to get text only.

https://codesandbox.io/s/4z08551xy4

Comment: No problems! If you could accept this answer, that would be greatly appreciated